# Deny access to certain files on server

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a newsletter subscription system and I would like to deny access to some files (such as the script that subscribes the user). The problem I ran into is that I need to deny access to the files for anyone coming from outside, but the scripts need to have access to each other.

For example, I have the following files:

- index.html
- subscribe.php

It should not be possible to access subscribe.php by typing the corresponding URL. However, index.html needs to be able to send the data that was input into a form to subscribe.php.

Here is what I tried so far:

I left index.html in my root directory and moved subscribe.php to the folder /restricted. I added the file .htaccess to the folder restricted. .htaccess just contains: `deny from all`

This gives me a 403 error when I try to access subscribe.php through the URL but it also gives me the same error when I submit the form in index.html

My question: what does my .htaccess file need to look like to archive what I want and why does what I tried not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem I ran into is that I need to deny access to the files for
>   anyone coming from outside, but the scripts need to have access to
>   each other.

You are incorrect; that's not consistent with what you say later:

> The problem I ran into is that I need to deny access to the files for
>   anyone coming from outside, but the scripts need to have access to
>   each other.

*you* are not submitting the form; the *client's browser* is submitting the form with a Web request.  Don't think of it like this:

> index.html needs to be able to send the data that was input into a
>   form to subscribe.php.

That's not what's happening.  `index.html` contains html that, when rendered on the client's browser, instructs the browser where and how to submit the  registration form.

There are a few things you could try:

- Forms are typically submitted with a POST request.  You could write `subscribe.php` to block GET requests and to expect the appropriate form submission information
- The Referer [sic] header could be checked to make sure the referring webpage was indeed your 'index.html'; but be warned that this, like any http header with a known value, is trivial to forge.
- PHP Sessions could be used to track a client's access of index.html before posting a submission form.  PHP sessions (typically) use client cookies to store a session 'token' that is then associated on the server side with a hash of information stored in a file or session cache.  When programmed well, the client never has access to this data and therefore would only be able to get the session variable 'HasVisitedIndex' or whatever set if you set it for them in the session.

There are probably other solutions, but as you can see none of them is a complete slam-dunk because of the stateless client-server model of HTTP.

Comment: I understand that my method does not work because the clients browser always needs to have access to the script?

Comment: Yes.  subscribe.php is accessed in fundamentally the same nature as index.html - or any other HTTP resource.  The _client_ accesses the resource, and your PHP runs on the _server_ to render pages, process input such as registration, access databases, etc. - all of which finishes running _before_ the result is then sent back to the client as an HTTP response.

Comment: Farrel Thanks, that cleared things up! One more question though: I have a config.php file which contains all the details to connect to my database, it does not do anything other than contain data. Is there any security issue if the client can access the file?

Comment: `config.php` in this usage would typically be included server-side with a php include, and the client doesn't need access to the file in that case.  The file probably doesn't output anything so it's not _necessarily_ a security risk, but bloking it in an .htaccess or similar is not inappropriate.  In my PHP programming days, I would have put config.php _above_ the document root rather than _within_ it ( so it wasn't publicly available) - the publicly accessible php directory need not be the "top" of your PHP application's directory structure.